# What are ebpf BPF_HISTOGRAM and how create it | Error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition

Tags: c, linux, ebpf

I like to know what is HISTOGRAMS in EBPF.

So for example below ebpf program creates histogram

Compiling it cause warning then bunch of errors `udp.c:7:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int] BPF_HISTOGRAM(counter, u64);`

SO in this tutorial about XDP it tells to create histogram I need to do `BPF_HISTOGRAM(counter, u64);` so where BPF_HISTOGRAM is #defined. Also what needed to be a type specifier in above waring so if I am doing `BPF_HISTOGRAM(counter, u64);` so I am assuming it wil be expended to something like `u64 counter` so if thats the case there here u go I have type specifier than what else is it complaining about in clang command `root@fawad:/home/fawad/bpf# clang -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/  -O2 -Wall -target bpf -c udp.c -o udp.o`

How how to get rid of these errors and a warning if I try to compile with above command

```
Errors like : IPPROTO_UDP not found
use of undeclared u64
use of undeclared counter,(if I am assuming right in above question text why this warning and error about counter and histogram)
```

So I have this simple code

```
#define KBUILD_MODNAME "udp_counter"
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>

BPF_HISTOGRAM(counter, u64);

int udp_counter(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;

    if ((void *)eth + sizeof(*eth) <= data_end)
    {

        struct iphdr *ip = data + sizeof(*eth);
        if ((void *)ip + sizeof(*ip) <= data_end)
        {

            if (ip->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP)
            {

                struct udphdr *udp = (void *)ip + sizeof(*ip);
                if ((void *)udp + sizeof(*udp) <= data_end)
                {
                    u64 value = htons(udp->dest);
                    counter.increment(value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
 

   return XDP_PASS;
}
```

Throws error

```
udp.c:7:1: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
BPF_HISTOGRAM(counter, u64);
^
udp.c:7:15: error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition
BPF_HISTOGRAM(counter, u64);
              ^
udp.c:22:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'IPPROTO_UDP'
            if (ip->protocol == IPPROTO_UDP)
                                ^
udp.c:28:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'u64'
                    u64 value = htons(udp->dest);
                    ^
udp.c:29:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'counter'
                    counter.increment(value);
                    ^
udp.c:29:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'value'
                    counter.increment(value);
                                      ^
1 warning and 5 errors generated.
root@fawad:/home/fawad/bpf# gedit udp.c 

(gedit:7386): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:24:34.572
```

https://dev.to/satrobit/absolute-beginner-s-guide-to-bcc-xdp-and-ebpf-47oi

Comment: also not quite sure if ebpf is so hot then why these errors R not mentioned on internet, hasnt anyone already encountered these error ever

Comment: If BPF is hot, it doesn't have that many developers in my experience. Most BPF developers are also already familiar with kernel development or at least C, so less likely to run into issues maybe.

Comment: Could you share the bcc script you are using to compile this program? What bcc version are you using?

Comment: @pchaigno I dont have bcc or dont remenber installing it, I am using C ebpf program that use `BPF_HISTOGRAM(counter, u64);` and userspace program that uses `libbpf`(but thats for later). Why does it matter bcc I like to use for right now libbpf and do userspace programs in C/C++

Comment: @pchaigno I did some research and looks like this is bcc structure BPF_HISTOGRAM. so is there any similar data structure in libbpf can u tell if yes then how to convert use of Histogram in this program to libbpf version

Comment: `Errors like : IPPROTO_UDP not found
use of undeclared u64
use of undeclared counter,` <<-- start at the top; you are missing headers (definitions) The `u64` (typedefs/#defines) are from BSD network code , before uint_64 existed. Also: BPF_HISTOGRAM doesn't exist in (my copy of) linux/bpf.h

Comment: @wildplasser yes it does not exists in linux/bpf.h as pchaigno pointed out I think she was refereing to bcc, which is other library, But I found xdp/ebpf examples and tutorial related to github there is a repository

Comment: `BPF_HISTOGRAM` is specific to bcc. You could check how it is defined and create the same: https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/160c9b63a25c30ebe6b3e8481003dac72fe35a4a/src/cc/export/helpers.h#L316-L327.

Comment: @pchaigno more interested in libbpf for now